# Why array showing blank output?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input, output

```
import java.util.*;

public class javabasics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of array: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Enter the elements of array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int idx = 0;
        int ans[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] >= 0) {
                ans[idx] = arr[i];
                idx++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < 0) {
                    ans[idx] = arr[i];
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                System.out.print(ans[i] + " ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Question is :
Given an unsorted array arr[] of size N having both negative and positive integers, place
all negative elements at the end of array without changing the order of positive elements
and negative elements.
Input :

N = 8

arr[] = {1, -1, 3, 2, -7, -5, 11, 6 }

Output :

1 3 2 11 6 -1 -7 -5

---

the code is not stoping to take input from the code and if i want to add greater than the size of array it bounces what should i do ?

Comment: The code is stopping to take inputs, it's just that you print the "Enter the number..." message only once so you think it's not (but it is).

Comment: As for the size, arrays are initialized with a size and you can't resize them (not without creating a new array and copying the previous values into it). If you want to dynamically size your collection, you should use something like a List

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you missed the closure of the first `for() loop`. And also you had some indexing issues.

I checked and fixed the code. Please compare it with your current code and learn from it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of array: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Enter the elements of array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int idx = 0;
        int ans[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] >= 0) {
                ans[idx] = arr[i];
                idx++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < 0) {
                ans[idx] = arr[i];
                idx++;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print(ans[k] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @UdayDeshmukh please set my post as an answer.